# Access Dynamic Route Parameters from View - ember.js

Tags: ember.js

if i got a route in ember.js which has a dynamic segment called ":albumid", how do i access this from within the view?

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    route: "/:albumid"
})
```

The Parameter is set like this:

```
gotoAlbum = function(r,e) {
    router.transitionTo("album", {albumid: StuffThatReturnsTheAlbumid});
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to use the albumid param in the `deserialize()` method of your route to return a context object. This context will be passed into `connectOutlets()` for your route. Within `connectOutlets()` you can pass the context along to the controller and/or view.

In the example below, an AlbumController will be created in which its `content` property is set to be the context passed into `connectOutlets()`. An AlbumView will also be created, which will have access to the controller's `content`:

```
Ember.Route.extend({
  route: "/:albumid",

  serialize: function(router, context){
    return {albumid: context.get('albumid')};
  },

  deserialize: function(router, params){
    // return a context object that will be passed into connectOutlets()
    return App.store.find(App.Album, params.albumid);
  },

  connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
    // context comes from deserialize(), and will be passed in as the
    // content property for AlbumController
    router.get('albumsController').connectOutlet('album', context);
  }
})
```

Comment: This is outdated. `deserialize` does not exist anymore.